# javaScriptにおけるエラー処理は、何のために行うのですか？　処理継続するため？？

Tags: javascript

**画像読込失敗時のエラー処理として、下記のような感じでエラーオブジェクト(？)を捕捉後、単にalert表示させているコードがあったのですが、**

```
addEventListener('error'
```

エラー処理は、一般的には何のために行うのでしょうか？
・javaScriptの場合、画面にエラー表示が出ないので、そこまで気にしなくても良いような気もするのですが…

---

**例えば、画像読込失敗した場合、それを回避することは出来ないので、alert表示させてもしょうがないと思うのですが。**

・デバッグのため？
・それとも、そこでjavaScript処理を止めず、それ以降に行われる別のjavaScript処理を処理継続するためですか？

---

**画像読込失敗がどういう原因で発生するか思い浮かばないのですが、それぐらいのサーバの状況なら、他でも正常に動作しない状況に陥っていると思うのですが…**
・エラーオブジェクト処理とか例外処理は、画像読込する場合でも記述するものでしょうか？

Comment: 引用されているコードが途中で切れているようです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ブラウザでのエラーハンドリングは

- エラーが発生したことをサーバーに送信し、ログ収集する
- エラーからの回復処理

  - 時間をおいてリトライする
  - キャッシュサーバーから取得できなかった場合は別サーバーから取得する

など、状況に応じた処理が考えられます
エラーが発生しても何もしないのであれば、エラーハンドリングは不要だと思います

今どき画像ファイルの取得に失敗したことは開発者ツールに表示されるので、わざわざ JavaScriptで画像取得失敗捕捉 => alert をする必要はありません
なので、記述のコードは無知からくる単なる無駄なコードなのではないかと思います...